# IP connectivity to other countries ? mirror ? what is it?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to have an IP to act as a local IP in different countries ?

For example the ip 193.105.173.105 which seems to be located in US but is handled by RIPE.net

Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) says that RIPE NCC handles Europe, the Middle East, and Central Asia.

So im quiet at loss on what they are doing would appreciate if some one were able to explain me how is the connectivity done in this case and how ?

Taking a closer look at the tracert all I can really see is NA but yet that ip information is handled by RIPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IP can be announced via [BGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bgp) from different geographic locations at the same time. This is referred to [anycast IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast). So they probably own the IP block themselves and either announce it now from a different place from which they registered it or announcement from multiple places.

The whois of the IP you gave is registered to http://www.trionworlds.com/en/ -- which looks like it is a global company. So my guess is the people in Europe bought the block but it is announced from the US.

Not sure what the official policy on doing that is with RIRs though.

Comment: If you Whois the IP thats what it looks like

Comment: I dont really know about the policy and everything, it just got my interest because I was in Europe and tried some games of them, then went back brazil and then went to US and I saw no difference AT ALL whenever I was their connectivity was always incredible, then I was trying to locate their provider, and this much was all I could find ehhe. thanks for your good answer, it does explain a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The location you see in whois does not necessarily have anything to do with the location the IP is actually located it.  It's probably a European based company that has servers in the US.  With bigger companies, they tend to have their own IP allocations from RIPE/ARIN/etc, and some datacenters will permit you to use these instead of datacenter owned IP addresses.

This really is a very, very common thing, and it's probably nothing tricky like anycast.

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific situation I can only guess, Its possible that company has their own net block in this case a /24 and has servers and/or a office here that announces that IP under BGP, so they don't have to get another net block or rent them from the ISP.